# unity problems with Mobile control rig and networking

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile

So I am using unity to make a multiplayer top-down shooter for IOS. Most of the networking is coming along great but just one issue is really biting my behind. So I am a bit of a beginner so I am using the standard assets CrossPlatformInput Control rig (modified a little) to control my player. The Input works ok on the network but whenever I connect as a client to the game, the mobile control rig positions are off. when I touch the they snap to fit to a smaller screen. I suspect the problem is that when I start the game, the canvas size is different to the next frame when it sets to the right screen size. other than that, I have do Idea. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i just fixed it I just edited the script to set the default position of the joysticks during OnPointerDown() and everything works well!